# Change UIReturnKeyType on UITextView change

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to change the return key from `default` to `done` when the user enters a string inside my `UITextView`. I'm attempting to do this inside `textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` but the return key changes only after I tap inside another `UITextView` (with a different return key type) and come back to the original text view. It does not happen immediately, after the string has been entered.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    myTextView.returnKeyType = myTextView.text.isEmpty ? .default : .done
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant update the keyboard once it is open.
You can update it by just closing and opening at the same time. So put this at the bottom

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

   textView.returnKeyType = ert..text.isEmpty ? .default : .done

   textView.resignFirstResponder()

   textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting `myTextView.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true`. It grays out the 'Done' button and makes it blue when the user starts typing!